# How to extract a list of active stock holdings from a data table using multiple filter criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hopefully, someone can help me. I'm quite stuck for a while now. Thank you for your time!!

**The Goal**:
Extract a list of active stock holdings from a data table using a function. The holdings are called tickers, the quantity is the number of stocks. The catch is that the filter function must only include the "Buy" and "Sell" options from the "action" column so only the active tickers with a quantity of more than 0 are displayed.

**My current function**:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Degiro_Transactions[Ticker];SUMIF(Degiro_Transactions[Ticker];Degiro_Transactions[Ticker];Degiro_Transactions[Quantity])<>0)))
```

**The problem:**
My current function lists all tickers and sums the total quantity. Only the active tickers (Buy action + Sell action) should be displayed but I don't know how to do this. So there should be an extra filter that only displays the ticker if the quantity of "Buy" and "Sell" is positive.

This is the data table:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsEFj.png

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot doesn't show any *Action*s with a negative quantity, so I'm not sure that such a check for positive values is needed, but I *have* included it in the formula below:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Degiro_Transactions[Ticker],(Degiro_Transactions[Action]="Buy")*(Degiro_Transactions[Quantity]>0)+(Degiro_Transactions[Action]="Sell")*(Degiro_Transactions[Quantity]>0)))
```